# System text causing 403 forbidden error in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have a simple form that is submitting to a post.php file . 
This form has input fields . If the text written in any of these input field is : `System something` , then I get a 403 forbidden error .

However , if I write the same System in quotes i.e `"System"` then it works fine .

It seems like that System is being treated as a command here and what I write after that is being treated as the parameter .

The code is not even reaching post.php . Even if I delete the post.php file , I still get a 403 error instead of a file not found error . Maybe it is something to do with Apache .

Please advise .
Below is the form :

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" name="form1">
                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0">
                <tbody><tr valign="top">
                  <td>Title</td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="title" name="title"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Company</td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="company" name="company"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Responsibilities</td>
                  <td><textarea id="responsibilities" rows="7" cols="55" name="responsibilities"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Position Requirements</td>
                  <td><textarea id="requirements" rows="7" cols="55" name="requirements"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Contact</td>
                  <td><textarea id="contact" rows="7" cols="55" name="contact"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Contact Name </td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="contact_name" name="contact_name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Contact Title </td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="contact_title" name="contact_title"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Address 1</td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="address1" name="address1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Address 2</td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="address2" name="address2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Contact Phone </td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Contact Fax</td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="contact_fax" name="contact_fax"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Contact Email </td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="contact_email" name="contact_email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>Contact Website </td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="" size="40" id="contact_website" name="contact_website"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add Job" name="Submit"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody></table>
</form>
```

Here are the HTTP headers sent :

```
(Request-Line)  POST /admin/jobbank/post.php HTTP/1.1

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100401 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.9

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate

Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

Keep-Alive  300

Connection  keep-alive

Referer jobbank/add.php

Cookie  PHPSESSID=bc679ded5a7f7650692084042c137d77

Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length  188
```

The HTTP response received :

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Date    Tue, 31 Aug 2010 09:52:16 GMT

Server  Apache/1.3.41 Ben-SSL/1.60 (Unix) mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a mod_fastcgi/2.4.2 mod_throttle/3.1.2 Chili!Soft-ASP/3.6.2 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_perl/1.30 PHP/4.4.9

Keep-Alive  timeout=15

Connection  Keep-Alive

Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got a wacky Apache config - but please do post the post.php file you're submitting to, even if you think it's not relevant. Also, check the permissions on the post.php file to make sure that Apache is allowed to load it.

Comment: Could you please provide the version of your Apache? Furthermore is there a packet filter between you and the server?

Comment: @Stephen - the post.php is fine as if I enter normal text it does submit . The permissions are also fine . I just checked . 
@coding.mof - No there is no filter between me and the server .

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have some protection module for Apache, that checks GET and POST variables for suspicious values like http://www.modsecurity.org/

You need to tune it or turn it off.

I think they are problematic most of the time...